# modifying the loop multiple times with arguments passed through ajax to wp_query

Tags: wp-query, loop, ajax

I am trying to create a post filter for my website.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input[id='brand']").click(function() {
        var key;
        var value;
        var checked;
        var check = $(this).prop("checked");
        if (check) {
            key = $(this).attr('id');
            value = $(this).val();
            checked = 'true';
        } else {
            checked = 'false';
        }
        var ajax_url = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        var data = {
            'action': 'filter_posts_by_meta',
            'checked': checked,
            'key': key,
            'value': value,
        };
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: ajax_url,
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                jQuery('#sortid').html(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the php script:

```
function ajax_filter_posts_by_meta () {
    global $wp_query, $wp_the_query;

    //$compare= isset($_POST['compare']) ? $_POST['compare'] : '';
    $key = isset($_POST['key']) ? $_POST['key'] : '';
    $value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
    $checked = isset ($_POST['checked']) ? $_POST['checked'] : die();

    //if ($checked != 'true'){}

    $filterargs=   array(array($qv) , array(
        array(
            'key' => $key,
    //       'compare' => $compare,
            'value' => $value,
        ),
        ) ,
    );


    $wp_query= new Wp_Query($filterargs);
    $qv=$wp_query->query_vars;

    while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title();
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endwhile; 
    die();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the query keeps getting **reset** every time a user clicks on an input box with the id brand. What I want to do is to modify the query and re-run it. At this point i have not written the code to 'unmodify' the code when a checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wp_localize_script` to save your current query to JS variable. Then you should send it using ajax and modify it and send it back to have access to it in the future.

```
global $wp_query;
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-pagination', 'ajaxpagination', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'query_vars' => json_encode( $wp_query->query )
));
```

[This article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/?rad=b&utm_expid=3606929-86.PHoDXYJeQYmWFQIujGOFZg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F) should help you handle the issue. Especially part with query_vars there is quite good explanation.